# conditional block not triggered when NaN !== 'number' Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing an array calculator on code wars. I have a function that checks the array for a valid sequence of numbers and operators. My function validSequence() is not return false when it is supposed to. The error in this test array:

```
Test.assertSimilar(validSequence(['10', '+', '20', '*','3', '*']), false)
```

is not being caught by this line in validSequence()

```
if(typeof parseInt(arr[arr.length-1]) !== 'number'){
    return false;
  }
```

and I don't know why. It gives a NaN as expected, so I don't know why it doesn't enter the block and return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `NaN` has the number type. Instead, use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to detect if [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) returns a rational number.

```
if(isNaN(parseInt(arr[arr.length-1]))){
    return false;
  }
```

`parseInt` will always return a rational number, or `NaN`, so there is no reason to check the variable type, as it will always be `'number'`.